# How can i color or texture each faces of a loaded .obj file?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm doing a 3D object texturing and coloring website. (For example a kitchen set. I want to change color or texture the kitchen cupboards, marble and fridge.) I'm loading the 3d kitchen set model on website. Customer should be able to see in any color and pattern of each faces. How can i color and texture the each faces of a loaded object?

I'm loading the 3D objects (.obj) with loadModel in p5js. I tried MeshFaceMaterial and get the geometry values of .obj file but i couldn't do it.

This is my load codes

```
let angle = 0;
let cat;
let myModel;
function preload() {
  cat = loadImage('cats/cat2.jpg');
  myModel = loadModel('OBJ.obj');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, WEBGL);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  rotateX(angle);
  rotateY(angle);
  rotateZ(angle);
  translate(0, 0, 0);//mouseX
  //texture(cat);
  model(myModel);
  angle += 0.01;
}
```

I expect to change color or texture every faces of a 3D object.

Comment: take a look at this: [JS WebGL](https://delphic.me.uk/tutorials/webgl-text)

Comment: then find the topic `Creating the WebGL texture` on that post

Comment: Thank you for that but I saw that. It texture and color the all faces. I want to texture and color different each faces of a loaded 3d object.

Comment: you will need to do UV mapped texturing

Comment: I couldn't find anything for loaded object(.obj file). Can you link something to try ?